# Shipping multiple APKs on gradle

Tags: android, gradle, fresco

According to the fresco document http://frescolib.org/docs/multiple-apks.html , I add flowing code to the gradle build:

```
android {
    ...
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But I got an error when build the android project:
`Error:Task with name 'packageRelease' not found in project ':app'.`
Am I missing something?

I have just find the reason, I use a lib to analyze the crash called bugly, so I add flowing code to my gradle config:

```
// project gradle.build
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
classpath 'com.tencent.bugly:symtabfileuploader:1.3.9'

}
// app gradle.build
apply plugin: 'bugly'
bugly {
   appId = 'xxxxxx'
   appKey = 'xxxxx'
}
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.tencent.bugly:crashreport:1.2.9'
}
```

And it will cause the `task not found`, but I still don not know how to solve it.

Comment: This exact code works for me for a minimal example that just includes Fresco and displays a simple DraweeView.

How does your build.gradle for your app look like, what Gradle version do you use etc.?

Comment: My gradle version is 2.13, and now I find the reason caused this issue. Have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at https://github.com/BuglyDevTeam/Bugly-Android, they have an explanation how to set up ABI filters and that you have to specify `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`. Not sure if the old NDK can be used for ABI splits but you can see if it works.

If it doesn't work, you can try their [option 2](https://github.com/BuglyDevTeam/Bugly-Android#%E6%96%B9%E5%BC%8F2-%E6%89%8B%E5%8A%A8%E5%AF%BC%E5%85%A5) to manually include pre-compiled libraries, which should be compatible with ABI splits.

You can also raise an issue on their GitHub page about this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, this has confirmed to be a bug and I have feedback to the bugly team. And next time, I will new an issue on their github page